# how to deal with ACK and DATA one after the other in I2C efr32fg14

Tags: embedded

in I2C We have the IF register to catch the ACK from the slave ,
And we have I2C0->RXDATA to catch the recieved data .
But as shown in the diagram bellow i cant code
Pseudo code:
check if ACK was recieved
wait a little and catch the input data with I2C0->RXDATA.

what is the method of handling two types of data intended for different registers coming one after the other?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the source code of the vendor's I2C libraries.  Even if you decide to write your own, seeing how the hardware was used by the software co-workers of the hardware designers should be clarifying.  If you're asking how to write an I2C driver, that's really beyond the scope of this site, and asking how to do it sort of defeats the purpose of writing your own uninformed by the vendor code.

Comment: Hello Criss, i have written  till now the code, i am only asking for an idia of dealing with it.

Comment: Not really.  Either you understand how I2C works, or the code you wrote isn't really applicable.   Start by studying code written by someone who _did_ understand how I2C works.

Comment: I do undesrand how it works,i ask specifically regarding a certain part, and only as advice not to write for me

Comment: That questions reveals that no, you really don't understand how it works.  Study the vendor code, which will be written with the awareness that it's the state machine in the MCU's I2C peripheral engine which "knows" when a given word has been transferred because it knows when it has produced the right number of clock cycles, and will signal that in a status register bit or interrupt depending on configuration.

Comment: Thats because i didnt publish the whole code i have written so far.but its not the correct impression you got.

Comment: I only ask an advice regarding a specifical place in the diagram.

Comment: Asking that questions demonstrates that you fundamentally do not understand how it works: you cannot use the ACK to know when the data is transferred, because that is not what it means.  Rather the ACK means that its okay to proceed with generating the clock pulses which will cause the data to be transferred.   The data will be received when those clock cycles are done.  The ACK that follows actually goes the _other_ way, telling the peripheral that you received the data.

Comment: @rocko445 shouldn't the reception of ACK be part of the function that transmits the slave address?

Comment: Surely the MCU programming manual has that info. All other MCUs do. If this MCU does not have it, then complain to manufacturer or change MCU.

Comment: @jsotola Sending slave address or data to slave gets an ACK back from the slave if it recognizes the address or accepts the data. Transferring data from slave needs an ACK from MCU to continue transfer.

Comment: @Justme I understand the purpose of ACK and that both devices send it ... I am saying to rocko445 is that the ACK at the begining of the red marked section belongs to the slave address exchange ... the data exchange should not be expected if the slave address exchange fails